# Place the path of a script in environment variables when installing the package

Tags: r

I am creating a package and I would like it to be used from the terminal. I wish we could call my script from the terminal.

I created an exec folder and put my script.R in it. I think that I have to put the path of my script.R in environment variables but how to do it so that at the time of the installation of the package the path of the script.R is put in the environment variables?

At the begining of my script.R i put this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
...
```